# phonegap jquery $.get json

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I'm having problems with jQuery in phonegap, the problem is when I load a `.json` file using 
`$.get("file.json")`, normally it will return all the data serialized as an Object, but in my app I just get a flat string.

So whats going on? Is phonegap missing a mime type for json or ?

```
$.get("file.json").done(function(data){

   typeof data // string

   // I can fix it like this, but I'll rather have the default behavior
   // of jquery.
   data = (typeof data == "string") ? JSON.parse(data) : data;    

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be the server may not be setting the proper MIME type (`application/json`) so tell jQuery explicitly that you are expecting json content from the server.

```
$.get("file.json", 'json').done(function(data){

   typeof data // string

   // I can fix it like this, but ill rather have the default behavior
   // of jQuery.
   console.log(data)  

});
```

Comment: It worked :) but i had to do it like this:
    $.get("file.json", function (data) {}, "json");